# Using PowerShell Parser for console application

Tags: powershell, parsing, automation, console, console-application

My larger PowerShell/console application requires OOP, etc. for easier development.

I know about parsers such as NDesk.Options and CommandLineParser but I want something to simulate cmdlet parsing as close as possible. E.g. Support parsing for:

```
MyProject.exe do-thing ("computer1", "computer2") -p "parameter"
MyProject.exe do-thing -cn ("computer1", "computer2") -p "parameter" -verbose
```

Is it possible to use [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Language_Parser_ParseFile_System_String_System_Management_Automation_Language_Token____System_Management_Automation_Language_ParseError____) or a another tool to simulate PowerShell parsing? Are there any examples and pitfalls to watch out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could use `Parser.ParseInput()` to parse the args and then extract the individual elements from the resulting `CommandAst`:

```
using System.Management.Automation.Language;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Token[] tokens;
        ParseError[] errors;
        Ast topAst = Parser.ParseInput(String.Join(" ", args), out tokens, out errors);

        // Find the CommandAst object
        CommandAst parsedCommand = topAst.Find(ast => ast is CommandAst, true);

        // Grab the command name
        string commandName = ((StringConstantExpressionAst)parsedCommand.CommandElements[0]).Value;

        // Grab the remaining command arguments from CommandAst.CommandElements
    }
}
```

I'd would probably store the arguments in a `Dictionary<string,string[]>`